# Why std::errc is identified as error_condition while std::io_errc and std::future_errc are identified as error_code

Tags: c++, c++11

I just noticed `std::errc` specializes `is_error_condition_enum<>` to make it identified as error conditions, while `std::io_errc` and `std::future_errc` instead specialize `is_error_code_enum<>` to be identified as error codes.

Is this discrepancy by design or ?

Moreoever, what exactly does ***portable error code*** of `error_condition` mean ? because enumeration values of `std::errc` are definitely varied on Linux and Windows.

Comment: The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/system.error.syn) requires that `std::errc` has exactly the specified list of members, their representations are specified as being the same as some macros taken from the Posix-C-Header `<errno.h>`. The representations of `std::io_errc` and `std::future_errc` members are implementation-defined. Further, cppreference says that they may even contain more members, but I can't find that in the standard. I agree that it's weird to claim that the error_conditions are portable when they depend on another header. But at least they should be portable on POSIX.